# mule 4 database bulk insert from sftp erroring out

Tags: mule4

I am trying to bulk insert data from an SFTP location to a local database table. The batch size is set at 1000. After around 3500 records or so I get the below error

org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException:  Found exception trying to obtain path /abc/xyz

I have using mule 4 sftp version 1.4.0.

SFTP Config

```
<sftp:config name="Workday_SFTP_Config"
    doc:name="SFTP Config" >
    <sftp:connection host="${sftp.host}"
        username="${secure::sftp.username}" password="${secure::sftp.password}" >
        <reconnection >
            <reconnect frequency="10000" count="5" />
        </reconnection>
    </sftp:connection>
</sftp:config>

<sftp:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" config-ref="Workday_SFTP_Config" directory="${sftp.workingdirectory}" recursive="false" outputMimeType="application/xml" autoDelete="true" moveToDirectory="${sftp.archivedirectory}" >

    <scheduling-strategy >
        <cron expression="${cron.expression2}" />
    </scheduling-strategy>
    <sftp:matcher filenamePattern="INT073_Inv_Job_Hist_*.xml" />
</sftp:listener>
```

I have reconnection strategy as below

```
    <reconnection >
        <reconnect frequency="10000" count="5" />
    </reconnection>
```

Below is the exception

```
ERROR 2021-11-10 11:44:15,798 [[MuleRuntime].uber.01: [hhmi-workday-outbound-investigator-job-history-int073].job-history.BLOCKING @1611613] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Found exception trying to obtain path /INT073/INT073-TEST org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Found exception trying to obtain path /INT073/INT073-TEST
 at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.command.AbstractFileCommand.exception(AbstractFileCommand.java:209) ~[mule-module-file-extension-common-1.3.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getFile(SftpCommand.java:92) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getFile(SftpCommand.java:80) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.copy(SftpCommand.java:223) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpMoveCommand.move(SftpMoveCommand.java:39) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.AbstractFileSystem.move(AbstractFileSystem.java:169) ~[mule-module-file-extension-common-1.3.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
 at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.source.AbstractPostActionGroup.apply(AbstractPostActionGroup.java:61) ~[mule-module-file-extension-common-1.3.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.source.SftpDirectoryListener.lambda$postAction$3(SftpDirectoryListener.java:285) ~[?:?]
 at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.source.SftpDirectoryListener.postAction(SftpDirectoryListener.java:280) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.source.SftpDirectoryListener.onError(SftpDirectoryListener.java:158) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.source.SftpDirectoryListener$onError$MethodComponentExecutor.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.GeneratedMethodComponentExecutor.execute(GeneratedMethodComponentExecutor.java:97) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.DefaultSourceCallbackExecutor.execute(DefaultSourceCallbackExecutor.java:127) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ComposedSourceCallbackExecutor.execute(ComposedSourceCallbackExecutor.java:42) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.SourceAdapter$DefaultSourceCompletionHandler.onFailure(SourceAdapter.java:348) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionsFlowProcessingTemplate.sendFailureResponseToClient(ExtensionsFlowProcessingTemplate.java:61) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.FlowProcessMediator.sendErrorResponse(FlowProcessMediator.java:456) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.FlowProcessMediator.lambda$policyFailure$10(FlowProcessMediator.java:390) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.api.functional.Either.applyLeft(Either.java:146) ~[mule-api-1.3.0-20210119.jar:?]
 at org.mule.runtime.api.functional.Either.apply(Either.java:178) ~[mule-api-1.3.0-20210119.jar:?]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.FlowProcessMediator.dispatchResponse(FlowProcessMediator.java:271) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.FlowProcessMediator.access$200(FlowProcessMediator.java:110) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.FlowProcessMediator$1.complete(FlowProcessMediator.java:247) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.FlowProcessMediator$1.complete(FlowProcessMediator.java:243) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.policy.CommonSourcePolicy.finishFlowProcessing(CommonSourcePolicy.java:66) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.policy.NoSourcePolicy$SourceFluxObjectFactory.lambda$get$6(NoSourcePolicy.java:90) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at reactor.core.publisher.OnNextFailureStrategy$ResumeStrategy.process(OnNextFailureStrategy.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onNextError(Operators.java:704) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:104) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.next(FluxCreate.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rx.FluxSinkRecorder$DirectDelegate.next(FluxSinkRecorder.java:196) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rx.FluxSinkRecorder.next(FluxSinkRecorder.java:68) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rx.FluxSinkRecorderToReactorSinkAdapter.next(FluxSinkRecorderToReactorSinkAdapter.java:35) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.MessageProcessors.lambda$childContextResponseHandler$18(MessageProcessors.java:556) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.event.AbstractEventContext.signalConsumerSilently(AbstractEventContext.java:272) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.event.AbstractEventContext.responseDone(AbstractEventContext.java:199) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.event.AbstractEventContext.lambda$error$4(AbstractEventContext.java:181) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.api.exception.FlowExceptionHandler.lambda$router$0(FlowExceptionHandler.java:78) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.api.exception.BaseExceptionHandler$1.accept(BaseExceptionHandler.java:61) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.api.exception.BaseExceptionHandler$1.accept(BaseExceptionHandler.java:52) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.event.AbstractEventContext.error(AbstractEventContext.java:183) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.construct.AbstractPipeline.lambda$null$19(AbstractPipeline.java:400) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at reactor.core.publisher.OnNextFailureStrategy$ResumeStrategy.process(OnNextFailureStrategy.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onNextError(Operators.java:704) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:104) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.next(FluxCreate.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rx.FluxSinkRecorder$DirectDelegate.next(FluxSinkRecorder.java:196) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rx.FluxSinkRecorder.next(FluxSinkRecorder.java:68) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.lambda$null$6(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:186) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.ErrorHandlerContextManager.resolveHandling(ErrorHandlerContextManager.java:101) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.exception.TemplateOnErrorHandler$OnErrorHandlerFluxObjectFactory.lambda$apply$1(TemplateOnErrorHandler.java:147) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:482) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:496) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.next(FluxCreate.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.exception.TemplateOnErrorHandler$1.accept(TemplateOnErrorHandler.java:192) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.exception.TemplateOnErrorHandler$1.accept(TemplateOnErrorHandler.java:182) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.ErrorHandler$1.accept(ErrorHandler.java:125) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.ErrorHandler$1.accept(ErrorHandler.java:111) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.lambda$null$7(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:191) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.lambda$notifyError$23(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:306) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at java.util.function.Consumer.lambda$andThen$0(Consumer.java:65) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.notifyError(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:307) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.lambda$getContinueStrategyErrorHandler$22(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:278) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at reactor.core.publisher.OnNextFailureStrategy$ResumeStrategy.process(OnNextFailureStrategy.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onNextError(Operators.java:704) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:104) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.next(FluxCreate.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rx.FluxSinkRecorder$DirectDelegate.next(FluxSinkRecorder.java:196) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rx.FluxSinkRecorder.next(FluxSinkRecorder.java:68) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor$1.error(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:366) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor$3.error(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:531) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator$1.error(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:185) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.AbstractCompletableMethodOperationExecutor.handleError(AbstractCompletableMethodOperationExecutor.java:84) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.AbstractCompletableMethodOperationExecutor.execute(AbstractCompletableMethodOperationExecutor.java:65) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.executeCommand(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:211) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.executeWithInterceptors(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:194) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$execute$1(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:113) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:15) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:75) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:46) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:43) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:37) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.api.execution.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:139) ~[mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.execute(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:112) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.executeOperation(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:563) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.prepareAndExecuteOperation(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:765) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.lambda$onEventSynchronous$19(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:465) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.onEventSynchronous(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:472) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.lambda$null$9(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:380) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:482) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:496) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:430) [mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:425) [mule-core-4.3.0-20210119.jar:4.3.0-20210119]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:345) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnValue$ScheduledScalar.run(FluxSubscribeOnValue.java:178) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_282]
 at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111) [mule-service-scheduler-1.3.2/:?]
 at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54) [mule-service-scheduler-1.3.2/:?]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_282]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_282]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282] Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Could not obtain
 attributes for path /INT073/INT073-TEST
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.exception(SftpClient.java:427) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.getAttributes(SftpClient.java:144) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getFile(SftpCommand.java:90) ~[?:?] ... 129 more Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: Permission denied, file: /INT073/INT073-TEST
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873) ~[?:?]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2225) ~[?:?]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2242) ~[?:?]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.stat(ChannelSftp.java:2199) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.getAttributes(SftpClient.java:139) ~[?:?]
 at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.command.SftpCommand.getFile(SftpCommand.java:90) ~[?:?] ... 129 more
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please add the complete error message. Be sure to include exception and root exception details if any. Also it would be good to share the configuration and usage of the connector as text XML, no screenshots.

Comment: I added the complete exception and also sftp config. As per your advise I used v 1.4.1 but still same issue.

Comment: Thanks. For reference the root error is `Permission denied, file: /INT073/INT073-TEST`

Comment: Thanks for the reply how is that possible? I can access it first 3 or so iterations and this happens.

Comment: It maybe a session timeout from the server side. Not sure if there is an issue in the connector preventing reconnection.

Comment: Thanks. I looked closely this happening because after 3000 plus records one fails and thats is causing the strange error. I am not using bulk insert(not batch). Is there a way to skip the failing record and move one. My error handler doesn't seem to be continue after error.